# Find Urban Fantasy Book with a mysterious guy who lives in the woods

Tags: story-identification, novel

This book I read long ago had a cover of a guy's face covered/made of roots of a tree like he himself was a tree or he merged into one. I do not remember much but the story centered on this guy and no one knew who he was. Everyone called him a **stranger**. The story is narrated from a girl's point of view when she sees the guy first and finds him intriguing.
I read it somewhere between 2002-2009. Those were my school years and my school had a great library. The most important thing I remember about it is that the way the guy's eyes were described as somebody who looks a lot older even ancient through his eyes. Also everyone around him got an eerie feeling about him.
She has a strange vibe of him. I think the book's name was **Stranger** but I do not seem to find it.
Also, I think this to be an urban fantasy  due to unknown origin of the boy and the cover of the book that I remember and I do not remember much of the story to describe it's genre. Please do help me find this book

Comment: I see you've asked a story ID on here before, can I ask you to check out the [same guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) you looked at last time and maybe see if there's anything else you can remember? Like when you read it and whether or not it was published long before or just before you read it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

[*The Stranger*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1504035577), a 1993 novel by [Caroline B. Cooney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_B._Cooney).

> Nicoletta meets the newcomer in art appreciation class. Jethro is brooding, mysterious, and dangerously attractive. She’s so mesmerized by him, she follows him home that afternoon. Or rather, home is where she thinks he’s going—until he walks past the edge of town and slips into the forest.
>   
> In the safety of the woods, Jethro’s power seems to surge: It’s as if the trees and boulders of the forest rise up to greet him. He’s so different, so beautiful, and so . . . inhuman. Before long, Jethro becomes her deadly obsession. The truth about Jethro is terrifying, and Nicoletta is already in too deep. Much too deep . . .

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to find this for so long!!!

Comment: @RushikeshWarde You're welcome!